# Authentication with Jenkins and Git

Tags: git, jenkins

I would like to use Jenkins with a repository on Bitbucket. For that, I created a ssh key with the user `jenkins` and the command `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "my_email"`. I added the public key on Bitbucket and I can clone a project with `git clone ...`.

But when I configure the project in Jenkins, I put the url `git@bitbucket.org:my_username/my_repository.git`

Here is the error :

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h git@bitbucket.org:skurty/ma-carte-augmentee-bo.git HEAD" returned status code 128:

stdout: 

stderr: ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory 
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

If I do ssh git@bitbucket.org, I get:

```
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
conq: logged in as my_username.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
Connection to bitbucket.org closed.
```

I also tried to create the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and put in it the public key, but same problem.

I also restarted jenkins with `sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins restart`

Thank you for your help :)

PS : I'm on a Debian Squeeze 64 bits

Answer (score 3):

The only way I found to make it work was removing the passphrase from my ssh keys. I guess the jenkins' git plugin was having trouble providing the passphrase, even when I set it in the advanced section of the Credentials plugin.

`$ ssh-keygen -p`

Provide the location of your private key, type your current passphrase and leave the new one empty.

Comment: You are right, I've seen that on a documentation that Jenkins DOES NOT manage to use passphrases on keys

Answer (score 3):

The problems comes from the fact that you NEVER logged in with user JENKINS on GIT

therefore, you should do the following :

log in JENKINS machine:

```
sudo su jenkins
ssh git@bitbucket.org
```

validate access.

Now you should be able to perform jenkins build with git

Answer (score 1):

Is the `id_rsa` or whatever your private key is called, in the `jenkins` user's home directory?

If you installed with a native package, the file should be located in `/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh` and the permissions for `/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh` should be `700` while the permissions of `/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa` should be `600`

Comment: Yes, I created the key with the user jenkins in /home/jenkins/.ssh and   the id_rsa is in /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh (with authorized_hosts...). The rights on the folder and the file are ok.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add your SSH Key on your BitBucket account as well in Manage_Account>>SSH_Keys>>Add Key

However, if you still face any issues: try out the step by step tutorial at:

http://777chmod.wordpress.com/2013/07/28/jenkins/

http://777chmod.wordpress.com/2013/08/01/ssh/

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.